# Bad Request trying to start node server at Azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying to run my node server.js there but it's not working.

I have sent all my files over the FTP in a folder called `api` (`wwwroot` is my website, so i need to run this server inside api folder).

Do i need to do something else or what?

Here's my server.js code:

```
//Dependecies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var cors = require('./cors');

//Database Configurations
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

//Passport Strategies
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//Morgan Logger
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Cookie Parser
app.use(cookieParser());

//bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Session
app.use(session({
secret: 'keyboard cat',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { maxAge: null, secure: false },
store: new MongoStore({
    url: configDB.url,
    collection: 'sessions'
})
}));

//Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

//CORS Setup
app.use(cors());

//Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Require the Routes
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);

//Start Server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server is Running!');
```

**EDIT** : 
When i type in the console, it stops for a bit and print "**Bad Request**".

Comment: You say "Azure cloud services", but are you really saying Cloud Services with Roles (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cloud-services/) or App Service (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-value-prop-what-is/)? For the latter, just follow this guide to deploy your Node app -- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-value-prop-what-is/

Comment: Hi, i'm using the Azure on Bizspark from microsoft, so basically i'm trying through the dashboard. I'll take a look at the articles above, thanks!

Comment: hi @WilliamXavier, any update yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly, the **400 BAD request HTTP error code** means that the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. You could check your request url, or post body.

Additionally, you can use the FTP tool to check whether there is a `web.config` file in your root directory on Azure Web Apps environment. If not, you can manually create one, you can refer to https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-express-nodejs-applications-in.html for a sample for an express based application.

Meanwhile, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide for more info about troubleshooting on node.js applications on Azure Web Apps.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for my late comment, it was the missing web.config as ou mentioned, after creating one, it worked just fine, thanks a lot!